# Unexpected output value with class constructor and class member variable

Tags: c++

I need to understand why `x(x + 1)` happened only after I get out of the constructor.

```
class A
{
protected:
    int x;

public:
    A(int x = 5) : x(x + 1)
    {
        cout << "In A::A x=" << x << endl;
    }

    operator int() const { return x; }
};

void main()
{
     A a1(10);
     cout << a1 << endl ;
}
```

I was thinking I will get:

```
In A:: An x=11
11
```

But somehow I've got:

```
In A:: An x=10
11
```

Comment: use `cout << "In A::A x=" << this->x << endl;` i think. The x used is the argument

Comment: Look into compiler warnings, and you will see that  constructor argument `x` shadows  filed name `x`. Unfortunately this is allowed by language, and not bring into compile time error.

Comment: Consider enabling more warnings:  g++ on lubuntu reports:   "warning: declaration of ‘x’ shadows a member of ‘A’ [-Wshadow]"  ....  now note how your question, "why the x+1 happened only after the A c'tor" is misleading, as the increment actually did happen where you expected it.  Debugger single stepping would also have revealed this, by simply examining the value A::x.

Answer (score 4):

You have two variables named `x`.

Inside the body of the constructor the argument variable will *shadow* the member variable. Whenever you use `x` inside the body of the constructor, it will be the argument, not the member.

To use the member variable you need to explicitly fetch it from the object, like `this->x`.

General tip: Don't use the same name for symbols in nested scopes. Besides solving this problem, it will also make the code easier to read and understand.

Comment: Another tip: Use `g++ -Wall`

Comment: `-Wall` is only "`-Wsome`". Use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`!

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter is hiding the member variable of the same name - your definition is equivalent to

```
class A
{
protected:
    int y;

public:
    A(int x = 5) : y(x + 1)
    {
        cout << "In A::A x=" << x << endl;
    }

    operator int() const { return y; }
};
```

When a parameter has the same name as a member, you need to explicitly refer to the member with `this->`.
(The initialiser list follows its own rules.)